# Proving the inequality $\frac{\mathrm{arccot} 2\sqrt{2}}{\pi\log\zeta(3)}-\frac{\log^2(1+e^{-\pi})}{\pi}>\frac{131e^2+422e-1151}{222e^2+279e-757},$

Tags: inequality

I have come across the following inequality in my studies

$$\frac{\text{arccot}2\sqrt{2}}{\pi\log\zeta(3)}-\frac{\log^2(1+e^{-\pi})}{\pi}>\frac{131e^2+422e-1151}{222e^2+279e-757},$$

where $\zeta(3)$ is Apéry's constant and $\log^2 x$ is the square of the natural logarithm of $x$. The RHS seems to be relatively close to the numerical value of the LHS, however I would like to know if there exists a way to prove this without relying on numerical computations.

Comment: If someone actually proves this in an answer I'm gonna eat my hat

Comment: I hope @Brian M. Scott sees this one after my discussion with him about your other question was deleted :-)  But you know what, I actually agree with the point you're making so I'll just let you.

Comment: Owww. I prefer the calculator. :p

Comment: The OP is clearly trying to troll us all.

Comment: Possibly [relevant](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ArcCot[2Sqrt[2]]%2F%28Pi*Log[Zeta[3]]%29-Log[1%2BExp[-Pi]]^2%2FPi%3C%28131E^2%2B422E-1151%29%2F%28222E^2%2B279E-757%29). Also see [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28131E^2%2B422E-1151%29%2F%28222E^2%2B279E-757%29-%28ArcCot[2Sqrt[2]]%2F%28Pi*Log[Zeta[3]]%29-Log[1%2BExp[-Pi]]^2%2FPi%29).

Comment: The OP is really trolling us. Actually, the inequality is not even true! I don't understand the upvotes!

Comment: @AlexSilva: it is true according to Mathematica v 9.0.1.  The RHS exceeds the LHS by about $0.000051455$.

Comment: @RonGordon, I don't think so. Did you see the Dejan Govc's references?

Comment: @RonGordon, actually is $\log^2 (1\color{red}+ e^{-\pi})$.

Comment: @AlexSilva: My apologies.  That said, the difference is of the order $10^{-20}$.  Machine precision is, at best $10^{-16}$.  You cannot conclude that the inequality is incorrect.  Even if false, the relationship is remarkable.

Comment: It is a trolling. :)

Comment: @AlexSilva: I disagree strongly.  You have a LHS and a RHS that seemingly have zero to do with each other, and they do have zero in common.  But they are within $10^{-20}$ of each other numerically.  That is amazing!  maybe one can derive any number of these idiocies with enough time on one;s hand, but it is not a troll.

Comment: @RonGordon, I think is a trolling because I don't see any purpose to prove inequalities like that. Is it amazing? Yes, but I can construct infinitely many inequalities such that LHS $\approx$ RHS, just for fun.

Comment: @RonGordon, See also the OP's name.

Comment: "I have come across the following inequality in my studies..."  No, you haven't.

Comment: To me, it looks like the OP constructed a complicated expression (the LHS) and then found a good approximation to it of the form $\frac{ae^2+be+c}{ue^2+ve+w}$. *That* would make it a random inequality.

Comment: @AlexSilva This trolling does not differ very much from questions about random integrals and sums starting with "Playing with my... euh... calculator, I discovered...". And such questions are quite appreciated here.